# Angularjs MV* (MVW) Design Pattern Involving ES6 - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angularjs-model, mvw

I have read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286917/angularjs-understanding-design-pattern?answertab=votes#tab-top) answers by Izhaki and Artem Platonov on Understanding Design Patterns and have some questions about this approach. They might be trivial, but I need some answers.

The final answer by Itzhaki made it seem to me that Angularjs design pattern is kinda MVW (MODEL VIEW WHATEVER), but I think I still haven't got 'Model' fully.

`View(DOM) -> Controller -> Service(Application login) -> Model(like resource)`

If this pattern goes in this way, **Where is Located all the information about the whole system?**

For example: Assuming that we have some properties about a "game" such as number of players, number of groups, etc.

**Where is all of this data being encapsulated?**

With es6 JS, I was thinking about making a class called Game with its own properties;

**Where do I need to locate this class?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is AngularJS considered MV\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165408/why-is-angularjs-considered-mv)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DIsplay angular 2 decorator metadata in the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626165/display-angular-2-decorator-metadata-in-the-browser)