# DIsplay angular 2 decorator metadata in the browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I m learning Angular 2 internal components and behaviours, and I m having a problem while trying to display the metadata provided by the different decorators.

For example, I need to access the metadata provided by the NgModule annotation :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    /* ... */
  ],
  imports: [
    /* ... */
  ],
  providers: [
    /* ... */
  ],
  bootstrap: [/* ... */]
})
export class AppModule { }

console.log(new AppModule());
```

But I can't find anything concerning the decorators metadata inside of that log information. Do you know where I can get these informations inside of my applications ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`reflect-metadata`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata).

```
npm install --save reflect-metadata
```

Then import it, and use it

```
import 'reflect-metadata'

let metadata = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', AppModule)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know which metadata I should look in to check Injectable and Inject ?