# Getting the component selector

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

'epimss-personnel'Given the following...

```
@Component(
    {
      selector: 'epimss-personnel',
      templateUrl: './personnel.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './personnel.component.css' ]
    } )
export class PersonnelComponent implements OnInit {
  personnel: IPersonnel = new Personnel();

  constructor( ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

... how can I get the selector string 'epimss-personnel' in PersonnelComponent programmatically?

## EDIT 1

When I add try the suggestion below I get the following:

```
compiler.es5.js:14582 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'AppRoutingModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1503) [<root>]
    at :4200/vendor.bundle.js:117324:44 [<root>]
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.es5.js:13953) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.es5.js:25134) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:25093) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:25055) [<root>]
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (core.es5.js:4786) [<root>]
    at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (core.es5.js:4772) [<root>]
    at Object.426 (main.ts:47) [<root>]
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap d227106…:52) [<root>]
    at Object.1132 (main.bundle.js:7) [<root>]
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap d227106…:52) [<root>]
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap d227106…:23) [<root>]
```

... the UI is not displayed either.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40626338/2587435)

Comment: My attempt at using reflect-metadata throws up errors in my app.module. It seems as if it the Reflect class is clashing with es5/6 polyphils. Have you seen this? It specifically introduces error related to App module.

Comment: @peeskillet Please see EDIT 1 in question above.

Answer (score 3):

With Angular 14, you have an option to get the metadata by `reflectComponentType(Targetcomponent)`

```
const mirror = reflectComponentType(StandaloneComponent)!;

expect(mirror.selector).toBe('standalone-component');

expect(mirror.type).toBe(StandaloneComponent);

expect(mirror.isStandalone).toEqual(true);
```

Source: https://netbasal.com/a-new-method-for-retrieving-metadata-about-angular-components-b494351dd130

Comment: If a component has multiple selectors, it will return string containing all selectors, not only current one.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not inside the component, you won't be able to use `ElementRef`, and the `Reflect` solution won't work with AOT.  Fortunately, there's an alternative when you know the target is a component:

```js
const components = [ PersonnelComponent ];
/*
  ...
  Anything that can be injected into
*/
constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  // For each component
  components.forEach(element => {
    // Get its resolved factory
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(element);

    console.log('Factory:', factory);
    console.log('Selector:', factory.selector);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(elRef:ElementRef) {
  console.log(elRef.nativeElement.tagName);
}
```

Comment: Good question, in Dart it's only `name`. Thanks for the hint. Seems like they return the same.